# Pass parameter to gradle Exec task

Tags: android, gradle

I have defined a simple Gradle task of type Exec and I'm trying to pass a parameter to that task when calling it from another task.

How does one do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to call a task from another task. Instead, declare two tasks and make one depend on the other. (Calling the internal `task.execute()` method is unsupported, and its behavior is undefined.) For cases where having a second task isn't feasible, there is a `project.exec {}` *method*, which has exactly the same API as the task.

Comment: OK I can relate to that. So say I add task B so that it depends on task A - how do I pass an argument to task B ?

Comment: You don't pass arguments to tasks. Perhaps try to describe the bigger problem that you are trying to solve, rather than your idea of implementing it.

Comment: My initial goal was to have a task of type Exec that would process different files based on an input parameter. But I have now turned the whole process upside down and simply do a loop over my files and for each I trigger my code. So in a way I guess I solved my own problem :/

Comment: A task has a fixed configuration. If a task is seemingly needed multiple times with different parameters in the same build, either declare multiple tasks, or solve the problem without using tasks.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out my initial approach was flawed and not "the gradle way". So after carefully rethinking the problem I turned everything upside down and now I "just" loop through my arguments and in turn execute the code for each argument.

Case here is a list of languages that each will be used as an argument in a command line.

```
task multiCommands << {
  def lang = languages.split()
  lang.each { locale -> 
    def output = exec {
      commandLine "my command that takes an argument", locale
    }
  }
}
```